# Creating a excel spreadsheet in vb.net Application not defined

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to create an Office 365 excel spreadsheet using vb.net. I have added the following reference. Microsoft,Office 16.0 Object Library to the project.
Anything with Excel. Errors as not defined.

What's missing?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objBook As Excel._Workbook

    Dim objBooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim objSheets As Excel.Sheets
    Dim objSheet As Excel._Worksheet
    Dim range As Excel.Range

    ' Create a new instance of Excel and start a new workbook.
    objApp = New Excel.Application()
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
    objBook = objBooks.Add
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
    objSheet = objSheets(1)
```

Comment: Microsoft Office Library is not the Excel library..

Comment: And COM interop is not an efficient way to create an excel file anywy - there are (free) libraries available which simply work on the file directly, rather than relying on trying to automate an instance of the application running on the machine (which isn't very reliable, requires excel to be installed, and isn't particularly quick either).

Comment: I Agree but this is what I have to use for a number of reasons.

Comment: Really? What prevents you from using a dedicated library exactly? There are several free ones you can download as nuget packages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am now in my stubborn phase and want to know why it doesn't work. I have look at several solutions on the web that show how it should be done and I want to figure out why it is not working.. Thanks again.

Comment: Well the first comment already explained to you one obvious issue. Follow the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic-net and notice what reference you have to add. Beyond that, we'd need to see the exact error message - paraphrased or abbreviated error messages are no use to us.

Comment: But seriously, stubborn or not, it's not worth your effort, just use a better tool for the job. If you notice from the pink box at the top of that documentation link, Microsoft isn't even supporting your approach fully anymore.

Comment: Just think, if you'd switched to EPPlus, you'd be over this error and probably be done with this part of the project by now. Life's too short

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to resolve your issue:

**Option 1**: Add Imports statement:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

**Option 2**: Specify the namespace

```
Dim objApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim objBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook
```

Try the following:

Add a Module to your project (name: HelperExcel.vb)

**HelperExcel.vb**

```
'Add Reference
'Project => Add Reference => COM => Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library

Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module HelperExcel

    Public Sub CreateExcelWorkbook(filename As String)
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        Dim excelApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        Try
            'create New instance
            excelApp = New Excel.Application()

            'suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

            'set Excel visability
            excelApp.Visible = True

            'disable user control while modifying the Excel Workbook
            'to prevent user interference
            'only necessary if Excel application Visibility property = true
            'excelApp.UserControl = false

            'add workbook
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add()

            'add a worksheet And set the value to the New worksheet
            excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add()

            'indices are 1-based in Excel; A1 = Cells(1,1)
            'excelWorksheet.Cells(1, "A") = "Product Code"
            'excelWorksheet.Cells(1, "B") = "Product Description"
            excelWorksheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Product Code"
            excelWorksheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Product Description"


            If excelApp IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
                'save Workbook - if file exists, overwrite it
                excelWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateExcelWorkbook): " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
                excelWorkbook.Close()
                excelWorksheet = Nothing
                excelWorkbook = Nothing
            End If

            If excelApp IsNot Nothing Then
                excelApp.Quit()

                'release all resources
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp)
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Usage**:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
    
    'write file to Documents folder (ex: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\TestExcel.xlsx)
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "TestExcel.xlsx")
    HelperExcel.CreateExcelWorkbook(filename)
End Sub
```