# How do I write data from access tables to excel

Tags: sql, .net, excel, vb.net, ms-access

I am looping through a table called `_TF_Tables` which contains the names of all tables within the database for which an Excel workbook needs to be created and filled with data from that table.

The below works in debug mode when I go line by line through the script. It creates an empty excel file, adds a new sheet with the name of the table and saves the workbook with the name of the table.

It then queries all the data from the table and writes it to the newly created Excel file.

the problem occurs when I run the script (not in debug mode).
It gives an error on the following line:

`adoConnnectionTF.Execute(strQuery)`

**ERROR**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The Microsoft Access
> database engine could not find the object 'TF_TT'. Make sure the
> object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
> If 'TF_TT' is not a local object, check your network

```
    Dim recordSetTables As Access.Dao.Recordset = dbTFFrom.OpenRecordset("_TF_Tables", Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
    Dim Excel As Object
    Dim tempTableName As String
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Object
    Dim strQuery As String
    Do Until recordSetTables.EOF
        tempTableName = recordSetTables.Fields(0).Value

        Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlWorkSheet = Excel.workbooks.add
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("path\" & tempTableName & ".xlsx")
        xlWorkSheet = Nothing
        Excel.quit()
        Excel = Nothing

        strQuery = "SELECT * INTO [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=path\" & tempTableName & ".xlsx].[" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & tempTableName & "];"
        adoConnnectionTF.Execute(strQuery)

        recordSetTables.MoveNext()
    Loop
    recordSetTables.Close()
    recordSetTables = Nothing
```

**OUTPUT OF strQuery:**
`"SELECT * INTO [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=path\TF_BLA.xlsx].[TF_BLA] FROM [TF_BLA];"`

It will create 1 sometimes 2 Excel files filled with data but eventually gives an error. Because it is not thrown all the time for the same table makes it hard to understand

The above is just my try of writing desired tables into an Excel file.
Alternative solutions will do as well.

**EDIT 1**
As suggested in the comments, I changed the recordset to DAO (it was ADO before), However, the error persists.

**EDIT 2**
As suggested in the comments, took the Dim statements outside of the loop, shortened the code and provided the output of the `strQuery`

**EDIT 3 / SOLUTION**
I found the solution.
The following creates the desired excel files from the tables in an access file

```
Dim dbTFFromAs Access.Dao.Database = workSpace.OpenDatabase(pathToTF)
Dim recordSetTables As Access.Dao.Recordset = dbTFFrom.OpenRecordset("_TF_Tables", Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
Dim tempTableName As String
Dim strQuery As String
Do Until recordSetTables.EOF
   tempTableName = recordSetTables.Fields(0).Value

   strQuery = "SELECT * INTO [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=\\DADI\MD\MDatabases\ExportedData\TT\" & tempTableName & ".xlsx].[" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & tempTableName & "];"
   adoConnnectionTF.Execute(strQuery)
   recordSetTables.MoveNext()

Loop
recordSetTables.Close()
recordSetTables = Nothing
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you surround the table name with [] in the openrecordset command?  Are you sure you’re using the same connection string in debug as release?  There are much easier ways to write data to excel, you could even have excel query access direct.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Hursey. unfortunately surrounding the table in square brackets did not solve the problem.  I am not doing anything differently while running in debug mode. actually it even creates the first excel file and fills it. it is on creating the second and sometimes the third file where it errs. I know I can have excel query access directly, but in this case I need them to be created from scratch. alternative approaches are also welcome

Comment: If I’m not wrong, adorecordsets are quite outdated nowadays.  Maybe you might have better success updating to oledb connections?

Comment: I changed the ADO in a DAO but that did not solve the problem

Comment: @Hursey ADO recordsets work fine in ms-access. As far as your code, it is doing some odd stuff - you only should need to open one instance of Excel - and do it outside of the loop. Same can be said for your Dim statements - that would cleanup your code a lot. Then you can identify the specific line that has the issue

Comment: Also - update your question with output from `Debug.Print strQuery` before your error line

Comment: You are coding in VB.net, not VBA?

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how to use OLE DB to read data from an Access database and use Excel Interop to insert it into an Excel workbook. It's been tested with Access 2016 and Excel 2016.

**Pre-requisites**:

- Microsoft Excel installed (>= 2007)

**Note**: You may consider using one of the following NuGet packages instead of using Excel Interop: [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1) (see also: [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)), [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML), or [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). There may be other ones available.

**Add Reference**

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Select **COM**
- Select Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library (ex: Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library)
- Click **OK**

**Create a class** (name: Helper.vb)

**Note**: Check the 'ToDo' items in the code below. You'll need to replace the column name in the Select statement (`SELECT tblName FROM _TF_TABLES order by tblName`) with the correct column name(s). The order defined here will determine the order that the worksheets will be created in the Excel workbook, as well as, the order of the worksheet tabs. Also, the connection string(s) used for the Access database may need to be changed. See [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) for more information.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Helper
    Private _connectionStringACE As String = String.Empty
    Private _connectionStringAceJet As String = String.Empty
    Private _connectionStringJet As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(filename As String)
        'ToDo: replace with connection string for the version that you're using
        'set value
        _connectionStringACE = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Persist Security Info=False;", filename)
        _connectionStringAceJet = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password=''", filename)
        _connectionStringJet = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};User Id=admin;Password=;", filename)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(filename As String, password As String)
        'ToDo: replace with connection string for the version that you're using
        'set value
        _connectionStringAceJet = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1}", filename, password)
        _connectionStringJet = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};User Id=admin;Password={1};", filename, password)
    End Sub

    Public Function AccessGetTables() As DataTable
        'get all Access tables including system tables

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStringAceJet)
            'open
            con.Open()

            'get Access tables
            dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

            Return dt
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function AccessGetDataFromSpecifiedTable(sqlText As String) As DataTable
        'get data from Access database

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Debug.WriteLine($"sqlText: {sqlText}")

        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStringAceJet)
            'open
            con.Open()

            Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlText, con)
                'get data
                da.Fill(dt)

                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function AccessGetUserTables() As List(Of String)
        'get list of tables that were user created

        Dim userTables As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        'get Access tables
        Dim dt As DataTable = AccessGetTables()

        If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                'Debug.WriteLine($"{row("TABLE_NAME"),-25} {row("TABLE_TYPE"),25}")
                If row("TABLE_TYPE") IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso row("TABLE_TYPE") IsNot Nothing AndAlso row("TABLE_TYPE").ToString() = "TABLE" Then
                    'add
                    userTables.Add(row("TABLE_NAME").ToString())
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Return userTables
    End Function

    Public Function ExcelCreateWorkbook(filename As String) As String
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        Dim excelApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        Try
            'get data from _TF_TABLES
            'ToDo: replace 'tblName' with correct column name(s)
            Dim dtTfTables As DataTable = AccessGetDataFromSpecifiedTable("SELECT tblName FROM _TF_TABLES order by tblName")

            'if no data was found, throw an exception
            'ToDo: if desired, return an error message instead
            If dtTfTables Is Nothing OrElse dtTfTables.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("Error: No data was found.")
            End If

            'create New instance
            excelApp = New Excel.Application()

            'set Excel visability
            excelApp.Visible = True

            'suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

            'disable user control while modifying the Excel Workbook
            'to prevent user interference
            'only necessary if Excel application Visibility property = true
            'excelApp.UserControl = False

            'add workbook
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add()

            'used to keep track of previous Worksheet
            Dim previousWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
                'set value
                previousWorksheet = CType(excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
            End If

            'loop for each table name found in _TF_TABLES
            For Each rowTf As DataRow In dtTfTables.Rows
                If rowTf(0) IsNot Nothing AndAlso rowTf(0) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                    'add a worksheet And set the value to the New worksheet
                    excelWorksheet = CType(excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=previousWorksheet), Excel.Worksheet)

                    'set name
                    excelWorksheet.Name = rowTf(0).ToString()

                    'get data from specified table
                    Dim dt As DataTable = AccessGetDataFromSpecifiedTable($"SELECT * FROM {rowTf(0).ToString()}")

                    If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Adding column headers for table: {rowTf(0).ToString()}")

                        'add column headers
                        For colIndex As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                            'indices are 1-based in Excel; A1 = Cells(1,1)
                            excelWorksheet.Cells(1, colIndex + 1) = dt.Columns(colIndex).ColumnName
                        Next

                        Debug.WriteLine($"Adding data for table: {rowTf(0).ToString()}")

                        Dim rowNum As Integer = 1
                        For Each rowDt As DataRow In dt.Rows
                            'increment
                            rowNum += 1

                            For colIndex As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                                Debug.WriteLine($"    rowNum: {rowNum}; colNum: {colIndex + 1}")

                                'indices are 1-based in Excel; A1 = Cells(1,1)
                                excelWorksheet.Cells(rowNum, colIndex + 1) = rowDt(colIndex)
                            Next
                        Next
                    End If

                    'set value
                    previousWorksheet = excelWorksheet
                End If
            Next

            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
                excelWorksheet = CType(excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)

                'delete existing worksheet
                excelWorksheet.Delete()
            End If

            If excelApp IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
                'save Workbook - if file exists, overwrite it
                excelWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (ExcelCreateWorkbook): " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
                excelWorkbook.Close()

                'release resource
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook)
                excelWorkbook = Nothing
            End If

            If excelWorksheet IsNot Nothing Then
                'release resource
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet)
                excelWorksheet = Nothing
            End If

            If excelApp IsNot Nothing Then
                excelApp.Quit()

                'release all resources
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp)
            End If
        End Try

        Return $"Created Excel Workbook: '{filename}'"
    End Function

End Class
```

---

**Usage** (create Excel workbook)

```
Private _helper As Helper = Nothing
          ...

Private Sub btnCreateExcelWorkbook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateExcelWorkbook.Click
    Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        ofd.Filter = "Access Files (*.accdb)|*.accdb|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        ofd.Title = "Choose Access Filename"

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
                sfd.Filter = "Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
                sfd.FileName = "Test_TFTables.xlsx"
                sfd.Title = "Choose Excel Filename"

                If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    'create new instance
                    _helper = New Helper(ofd.FileName)

                    'create Excel file
                    Dim result As String = _helper.ExcelCreateWorkbook(sfd.FileName)
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{result}")
                End If
            End Using
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

**Usage** (get table names from Access)

```
Private _helper As Helper = Nothing
          ...

Private Sub btnGetAccessTables_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetAccessTables.Click
    Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        ofd.Filter = "Access Files (*.accdb)|*.accdb|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        ofd.Title = "Choose Access Filename"

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'create new instance
            _helper = New Helper(ofd.FileName)

            Dim userTables As List(Of String) = _helper.AccessGetUserTables()

            For Each tbl In userTables
                Debug.WriteLine(tbl)
            Next
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

---

Here's the Access table definitions (and some data) that was used for testing:

**_TF_TABLES**:

[image]

[image]

---

**TABLE123**:

[image]

[image]

---

**Table456**:

[image]

[image]

---

**Table789**:

[image]

---

**Resources**

- [How to get list of Tables in MS Access using C# code](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vendettamit/how-to-get-list-of-tables-in-ms-access-using-C-Sharp-code/)
- [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)
- [Creating a excel spreadsheet in vb.net Application not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416147/10024425)
- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)
- [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)