# How do I unlock an Excel file that's been locked by code?

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop, excel-interop, file-locking

I'm using Windows 7 professional, Visual Studio 2012, and vb.net. This is a legacy program that can't be moved from this machine, so I'm unable to change where it's hosted.

I was attempting to read in an Excel file. It worked fine until I started checking some error handling.  Now it's left Excel files locked; I can't open or delete them.  I know I can copy them and look at the data.  What I'd like to do is clean up the files and remove them.  I tried a program called Unlocker that I've used on other files, but it didn't handle these.  How do I unlock and delete these files?

Here's the code.  I thought it should release the Excel files in the Finally block, but that doesn't seem to have worked.

```
        Private Sub ImportExcelFile()

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Dim ImportExcelSuccess As Boolean = False
        Dim listPriceChangeItems As New PriceChangeItemList

        Dim Item As New PriceChangeItem
        Dim strVendorProductNumber As String
        Dim strNewPrice As String

        Try

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) Then

                '****** Read in Excel file ********
                xlApp = New Excel.Application
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
                xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

                'Access the used range of the Excel file
                Dim usedRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
                Dim lastRow As Integer = usedRange.Rows.Count
                Dim lastColumn As Integer = usedRange.Columns.Count

                Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor

                Dim dt As DataTable
                dt = New DataTable("Import")

                For row As Integer = 1 To lastRow

                    If row = 1 Then

                        dt.Columns.Add("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                        dt.Columns.Add("name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
                        dt.Columns.Add("base_price", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
                        dt.Columns.Add("mfg_pn", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
                        dt.Columns.Add("item_id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                        dt.Columns.Add("new_price", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
                        dt.Columns.Add("price_change", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

                    ElseIf row > 1 Then

                        dt.Rows.Add(xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value _
                                    , xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value _
                                    , xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value _
                                    , xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value _
                                    , xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value _
                                    , xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 6).Value _
                                    , String.Format("{0:0.00%}", (xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 6).Value - xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value) / xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value) _
                                    )

                    End If
                Next

                If (VerifyProducts(dt)) Then

                    Dim app As frmBulkProductPriceChangeApproval = New frmBulkProductPriceChangeApproval(dt)
                    app.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                    app.Show()
                Else


                End If

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a file first.", "No file selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error importing file.  " & ex.Message)
            WriteDebug("Error reading price change items.  Filename " & filename & ".")
            WriteError(ex)
            Item.ItemChangeError = True
            Item.ItemChangeErrorType = PriceChangeErrors.SystemGenerated
            Item.ItemChangeErrorMessage = ex.Message
        Finally
            CloseExcel(xlApp, xlWorkBook, xlWorkSheet)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseExcel(ByVal xlApp As Excel.Application, ByVal xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook, ByVal xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet)
        Try
            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()

            releaseObject(xlApp)
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteDebug("Error closing excel file.  Filename " & filename & ".")
            WriteError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Here's the error I'm getting when I try to delete the file.  I checked Task Manager and no instances of Excel seem to be running.  I also tried deleting files from the command prompt with no success.

[image]

Comment: Check the task manager. Is the process still running when you try to delete the file?

Comment: See function "ExcelCreateWorkbook" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425). Ensure that Excel is closed. Then open Task Manager and kill any remaining Excel processes (Win10: also look under "Background Processes"). Alternatively, reboot your computer.

Comment: Excel is not running in the task manager.

Comment: `xlApp = New Excel.Application` starts Excel. You close the file only if there is an error. You can't delete an open file. The only tab that is interesting in Task Manager is the *Details* tab. The *Processes* tab is just a whole load of guess work based on program windows and tries to make sense of the *Details* tab for non technical people.

Comment: Windows also has a diagnostic tool called *OpenFiles.exe*. It purpose is to say what files have been opened from the network as Windows tracks this information. For speed reasons Windows doesn't track this information for local files. Windows can be configured to. Type `openfiles /?`. So `openfiles /local on`. Reboot. To see what files are open `openfiles /query`.

Comment: I thought xlWorkBook.Close() and xlApp.Quit() in the Finally block would close it.  Is there something else I need to do when there's an error to close the file and not get it locked?

Comment: My experience, not sure if it applies here.   During debug, I often have what sounds like similar issues with com automation.  Spent many hours trying to resolve, and quite a few questions here.  While annoying also found my problem only occurs when the debugger attached.  In release the instance cleanup code functioned perfectly