# Contact support for Excel 2016 version of .NET Framework 4 version

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, oledb

I developed a Windows program using .NET Framework, and added a function to read excel using oledb. However, Excel 2010 or 2019 versions work normally, but for users using Excel 2016, the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider cannot be registered on the local computer. error occurs. There was often a problem with the version, so I used to install the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable Package' from the ms download center according to the OS to solve it. say no. Is the problem only for excel 2016? Is it because the support for excel 2016 is cut off?

```
string oledbConnStr;// = string.Empty;

            //DataTable dtExcel;// = null;
            DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();

            try
            {

                if (sFilePath.IndexOf(".xlsx") > 0)
                {
                   
               
                    oledbConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'";
                }
                else
                {
                 
                    // excel 2003
                    oledbConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'";
                }

                OleDbDataAdapter adt;// = null;
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(oledbConnStr))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                    string sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();           
                    string sQuery = string.Format(" SELECT * FROM [{0}] ", sheetName);  
                    //dtExcel = new DataTable();
                    adt = new OleDbDataAdapter(sQuery, con);
                    adt.Fill(dtExcel);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
                if (msg == "error")
                {
                    msg = msg + "";
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                }

            }


            return dtExcel;
```

Comment: I recommend using a library that is independent of user have installed on their machines, like ClosedXML

Comment: [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) -- [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) -- [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Unable to use the Access ODBC, OLEDB or DAO interfaces outside Office Click-to-Run applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let's make full use of it.