# How to import Table from Access DB into Excel using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to import a table from Access into an Excel sheet.

I found some answer on Google saying to Dim a connection and recordset as `Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection`, but it doesn't work in VB.Net.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim file As String

ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
file = "C:/Downloads/db.accdb"

With ws.QueryTables.Add("OLEDB;" & file, ws.Range("A1"), "SELECT * FROM [TableName]")
    .Name = "Source Data Table"
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh(False)
End With
```

I don't understand how the connection from `QueryTables.Add()` works, and I  get an error at `.Refresh(False)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write data from access tables to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752423/how-do-i-write-data-from-access-tables-to-excel)

Comment: @user09938 I'm going to try, but it is a lot of code. Let me check it out :)

Comment: What you recorded was the process on creating a New Power Query Connection. Which Stay on the workbook when saved and you can just Refresh the data to bring in new data. Is there any reason this is not working for you, and you need to try to do it on VBA? I used to bring in data with VBA from Access on every DB project but since moving to Power Query it has really worked on every situation.

Comment: @RicardoA Well... it's not the same thing VBA into VB.Net. If there is something I need to import, I don't know what it is. In VB.Net I'm running the code on an Add In, not in a Module like it is used in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the error was this part:`

`ws.QueryTables.Add("OLEDB;" & file, ws.Range("A1"), "SELECT * FROM [TableName]")`

It should be like this:

```
ws.QueryTables.Add("OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & file, ws.Range("A1"), "SELECT * FROM [TableName]")
```

After that, the data was successfully added into Excel.