# Can Casting ComObject Properties be problematic

Tags: excel, vb.net, casting, comobject

So I dont know how Casting really works in detail

Working with excel comobjects I find it easily necessary to cast certain properties, because those properties come only back as `Object`

example:

```
_excel = New Excel.Application
_books = _excel.Workbooks
_book = _books.Open(path)
_sheets = _book.Worksheets
_sheet = DirectCast(_Sheets(0), Excel.Worksheet)  'This row
_range = _sheet.Range("A1","A20")
finallyNoComObjectAnymore = DirectCast(_range.Value(), Object(,)) 'This row
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_range)
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_sheet)
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_sheets)
_book.Close
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_book)
_books.Close
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_books)
_excel.Quit
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excel)
```

Does Casting somehow interfere with the genuine pattern of retrieving and cleaning?
Or does this in fact work just fine?

Comment: You should use [Try-Catch-Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement). There's a function named "ExcelCreateWorkbook" in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425) that may be helpful. You can use [DirectCast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator) instead of [CType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function).

Comment: Have you considered avoiding [Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia) and using NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools) instead? Also see [DocumentFormat.OpenXml Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1).

Comment: Is casting com objects problematic? The answer is yes and no.  Either way though, would almost go as far to say a necessary evil to ensure simple and robust applications.  Would also agree with the above comments, there are many 3rd party libraries (eg. OpenXml) available that significantly simplify handling office automations.

Comment: Casting is a normal COM operation and part of the most fundamental COM interface: see QueryInterface on IUnknown.

Comment: I understand why alternatives are commonly mentioned, but Im interested in if there is a way to use this correctly. I did not use CType. Try Finally makes sense, but it wont change the behavior of the code within the try block, so I didnt see a point adding this to the question. Being part of a COM interface means it is or is not problematic?

Comment: @aludebe: The reference to `CType` I made is in regards to the code in the referenced post mentioned in the comment.  If one enables [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement), then one needs to cast the Object to the appropriate type. See [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/) for more information.

Comment: Is enabling _Option Strict_ (ie: requiring early binding) problematic? According to [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/#advantages-of-early-binding), (under "Advantages of Early Binding"): _You should use early-bound objects whenever possible, because they allow the compiler to make important optimizations that yield more efficient applications_.

Comment: There has been some mention, on SO, that some have faced difficulties in achieving the desired outcome when late binding is disabled. I haven't faced any issues in my  usage of [Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia).

Comment: Well I also dont use any late binding. Do you think with Option Strict Off instead of DirectCasting it might change the behavior of cleaning up the used ressources?