# getting an error while uploading data through Microsoft Excel after updating Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, oledb

```
        ` string con =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + "; " +
        @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";`
```

*This is the connection string for OLEDB provider.*

The project is in .net6 web API. The complete scenario is when we upload large file of Excel and executer DB operation on the rows, then each rows is not getting inserted in DB after we updated Microsoft Access 2016. When we downgrade the version to 2010 then file gets successfully uploaded and all rows are processed.
Now the error is :The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I tried changing Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to 16

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "upload" means.

Comment: Is your Excel file `.xls` or `.xlsx`?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution),  [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/), and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid its .Xlsx file

Comment: Try `Excel 12.0` instead of `Excel 8.0`.