# Exporting data to Excel with multiple worksheets from MS SQL Database through vb.net

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

[image]
[image]

My task is to import the data from the test_import table into multiple sheets of the same excel workbook. What I am trying to achieve is to fill up specific cells in the selected sheet with selected data columns that I have in my MS SQL database through VB.NET.

I am currently undergoing my internship in a company and I never learn VB.NET before. However, my employer had assigned me this task. Hence, finding sources from internet and YouTube are my only option to self-learn VB.NET. Will be appreciate if there are source code or advice that could help me on my task!

```
    Dim oExcel As Object
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 1 Then
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
    End If
    oSheet.Name = "Requisition_Vendors"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "VDCODE"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "CURRENCY"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "RATE"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "SPREAD"
    oSheet.Range("F1").Value = "RATETYPE"
    oSheet.Range("G1").Value = "RATEMATCH"
    oSheet.Range("H1").Value = "RATEDATE"
    oSheet.Range("I1").Value = "RATEOPER"

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 2 Then
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(2)
    End If
    oSheet.Name = "Requisition_Detail_Opt__Fields"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "RQNLREV"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "OPTFIELD"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "VALUE"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "TYPE"
    oSheet.Range("F1").Value = "LENGTH"
    oSheet.Range("G1").Value = "DECIMALS"
    oSheet.Range("H1").Value = "ALLOWNULL"
    oSheet.Range("I1").Value = "VALIDATE"
    oSheet.Range("J1").Value = "SWSET"
    oSheet.Range("K1").Value = "VALINDEX"
    oSheet.Range("L1").Value = "VALIFTEXT"
    oSheet.Range("M1").Value = "VALIFMONEY"
    oSheet.Range("N1").Value = "VALIFNUM"
    oSheet.Range("O1").Value = "VALIFLONG"
    oSheet.Range("P1").Value = "VALIFBOOL"
    oSheet.Range("Q1").Value = "VALIFDATE"
    oSheet.Range("R1").Value = "VALIFTIME"
    oSheet.Range("S1").Value = "FDESC"
    oSheet.Range("T1").Value = "VDESC"

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 3 Then
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(3)
    End If
    oSheet.Name = "Requisition_Header_Opt__Fields"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "OPTFIELD"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "VALUE"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "TYPE"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "LENGTH"
    oSheet.Range("F1").Value = "DECIMALS"
    oSheet.Range("G1").Value = "ALLOWNULL"
    oSheet.Range("H1").Value = "VALIDATE"
    oSheet.Range("I1").Value = "SWSET"
    oSheet.Range("J1").Value = "VALINDEX"
    oSheet.Range("K1").Value = "VALIFTEXT"
    oSheet.Range("L1").Value = "VALIFMONEY"
    oSheet.Range("M1").Value = "VALIFNUM"
    oSheet.Range("N1").Value = "VALIFLONG"
    oSheet.Range("O1").Value = "VALIFBOOL"
    oSheet.Range("P1").Value = "VALIFDATE"
    oSheet.Range("Q1").Value = "VALIFTIME"
    oSheet.Range("R1").Value = "FDESC"
    oSheet.Range("S1").Value = "VDESC"

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 4 Then
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(4)
    End If
    oSheet.Name = "Requisition_Comments"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "RQNCREV"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "RQNCSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "COMMENTTYP"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "COMMENT"

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 5 Then
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(5)
    End If
    oSheet.Name = "Requisition_Lines"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "RQNLREV"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "RQNLSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "RQNCSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "OEONUMBER"
    oSheet.Range("F1").Value = "VDCODE"
    oSheet.Range("G1").Value = "ITEMNO"
    oSheet.Range("H1").Value = "LOCATION"
    oSheet.Range("I1").Value = "ITEMDESC"
    oSheet.Range("J1").Value = "EXPARRIVAL"
    oSheet.Range("K1").Value = "VENDITEMNO"
    oSheet.Range("L1").Value = "HASCOMMENT"
    oSheet.Range("M1").Value = "ORDERUNIT"
    oSheet.Range("N1").Value = "OQORDERED"
    oSheet.Range("O1").Value = "HASDROPSHI"
    oSheet.Range("P1").Value = "DROPTYPE"
    oSheet.Range("Q1").Value = "IDCUST"
    oSheet.Range("R1").Value = "IDCUSTSHPT"
    oSheet.Range("S1").Value = "DLOCATION"
    oSheet.Range("T1").Value = "DESC"
    oSheet.Range("U1").Value = "ADDRESS1"
    oSheet.Range("V1").Value = "ADDRESS2"
    oSheet.Range("W1").Value = "ADDRESS3"
    oSheet.Range("X1").Value = "ADDRESS4"
    oSheet.Range("Y1").Value = "CITY"
    oSheet.Range("Z1").Value = "STATE"
    oSheet.Range("AA1").Value = "ZIP"
    oSheet.Range("AB1").Value = "COUNTRY"
    oSheet.Range("AC1").Value = "PHONE"
    oSheet.Range("AD1").Value = "FAX"
    oSheet.Range("AE1").Value = "CONTACT"
    oSheet.Range("AF1").Value = "EMAIL"
    oSheet.Range("AG1").Value = "PHONEC"
    oSheet.Range("AH1").Value = "FAXC"
    oSheet.Range("AI1").Value = "EMAILC"
    oSheet.Range("AJ1").Value = "MANITEMNO"
    oSheet.Range("AK1").Value = "CONTRACT"
    oSheet.Range("AL1").Value = "PROJECT"
    oSheet.Range("AM1").Value = "CCATEGORY"
    oSheet.Range("AN1").Value = "UNITCOST"
    oSheet.Range("AO1").Value = "UCISMANUAL"
    oSheet.Range("AP1").Value = "CPCOSTTOPO"
    oSheet.Range("AQ1").Value = "EXTENDED"
    oSheet.Range("AR1").Value = "DISCOUNT"
    oSheet.Range("AS1").Value = "DISCPCT"
    oSheet.Range("AT1").Value = "UNITWEIGHT"
    oSheet.Range("AU1").Value = "EXTWEIGHT"
    oSheet.Range("AV1").Value = "WEIGHTUNIT"
    oSheet.Range("AW1").Value = "WEIGHTCONV"
    oSheet.Range("AX1").Value = "DEFUWEIGHT"
    oSheet.Range("AY1").Value = "DEFEXTWGHT"
    oSheet.Range("AZ1").Value = "NETXTENDED"
    oSheet.Range("BA1").Value = "DETAILNUM"

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 6 Then
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(6)
    End If
    oSheet.Name = "Requisitions"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "ISPRINTED"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "DATE"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "RQNNUMBER"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "VDCODE"
    oSheet.Range("F1").Value = "VDNAME"
    oSheet.Range("G1").Value = "ONHOLD"
    oSheet.Range("H1").Value = "ORDEREDON"
    oSheet.Range("I1").Value = "EXPARRIVAL"
    oSheet.Range("J1").Value = "EXPIRATION"
    oSheet.Range("K1").Value = "DESCRIPTIO"
    oSheet.Range("L1").Value = "REFERENCE"
    oSheet.Range("M1").Value = "COMMENT"
    oSheet.Range("N1").Value = "REQUESTBY"
    oSheet.Range("O1").Value = "DOCSOURCE"
    oSheet.Range("P1").Value = "STCODE"
    oSheet.Range("Q1").Value = "STDESC"
    oSheet.Range("R1").Value = "APPROVER"
    oSheet.Range("S1").Value = "ENTEREDBY"
    oSheet.Range("T1").Value = "HASJOB"
    oSheet.Range("U1").Value = "DETAILNEXT"

    Dim requisitions As Worksheet = oBook.Sheets("Requisitions")
    Dim range1 As Range = CType(requisitions.Range("$A:$U"), Range)
    range1.Name = "Requisitions"

    Dim requisitionLines As Worksheet = oBook.Sheets("Requisition_Lines")
    Dim range2 As Range = CType(requisitionLines.Range("$A:$BA"), Range)
    range2.Name = "Requisition_Lines"

    Dim requisitionComments As Worksheet = oBook.Sheets("Requisition_Comments")
    Dim range3 As Range = CType(requisitionComments.Range("$A:$E"), Range)
    range3.Name = "Requisition_Comments"

    Dim requisitionHOF As Worksheet = oBook.Sheets("Requisition_Header_Opt__Fields")
    Dim range4 As Range = CType(requisitionHOF.Range("$A:$S"), Range)
    range4.Name = "Requisition_Header_Opt__Fields"

    Dim requisitionDOF As Worksheet = oBook.Sheets("Requisition_Detail_Opt__Fields")
    Dim range5 As Range = CType(requisitionDOF.Range("$A:$T"), Range)
    range5.Name = "Requisition_Detail_Opt__Fields"

    Dim requisitionVendors As Worksheet = oBook.Sheets("Requisition_Vendors")
    Dim range6 As Range = CType(requisitionVendors.Range("$A:$I"), Range)
    range6.Name = "Requisition_Vendors"

    Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Execl files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    SaveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        oSheet.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        MsgBox("Excel File Created Successfully!")
    Else
        Return
    End If
    oBook.Close()
    oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```

Actually I had wrote a code to create excel file that looks the same like the excel file shown in png. I want to be able to import selected row only into selected cell respectively in the excel file. For example, I want to insert data in "ProjectCode" from sql into "RQNHSEQ" column in excel, data in "ItemCode" from sql into "Type" column in excel.

Sorry if I accidentally mislead about the goal of my task.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Excel has a wizard that will do this - suggest you start with that. A simple search on "excel import data from query" with find many tutorials and suggestions.

Comment: Here are some URLs and terms you can search for to help get you started: [System.Data.SqlClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8), [System.Data.OleDb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8),  [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia), You may also consider the following NuGet packages: [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML), [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), and DocumentFormat.OpenXml.

Comment: If you choose to use Excel Interop, you may find some code that you can adapt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416147/10024425) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425). However, Excel Interop is slow, so you may prefer using one of the other options mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: It is recommended to enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-option-strict-in-the-ide)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution to import data from SQL Server, to Excel.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '
     
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     
    Server_Name = "EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "NORTHWND" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]" ' Enter your SQL here
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

After importing data from the first table...

1. move the focus to another table

   SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]"
2. select a new worksheet...

   With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500")

You could create a SProc to do essentially the same thing; export to Excel, and call the SProc with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to read data from an SQL Server database and use Excel Interop to insert it into an Excel workbook. It's been tested with  Excel 2016.

**Note**: It is recommended to enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-option-strict-in-the-ide) for your project.

**Pre-requisites**:

- Microsoft Excel installed (>= 2007)

**Note**: You may consider using one of the following NuGet packages instead of using Excel Interop: [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-option-strict-in-the-ide) (see also: [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)), [ClosedXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2ki4.png), or [EPPlus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV3a4.png). There may be other ones available.

---

**Get SQL Server instance name**

- On the database server, open PowerShell and type the following:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\SqlServer  -Query "Select Name from __Namespace where Name like 'ComputerManagement%'" | ForEach-Object { $sqlMgmtVer = $_.Name; Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\$sqlMgmtVer -Class FileStreamSettings |Select-Object InstanceName }
```

[image]

Alternatively, open a cmd window and type the following:

```
sc query type=service | find /i "sql"
```

[image]

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425) for more information.

---

**Add Reference** (Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Select **COM**
- Select Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library (ex: Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library)
- Click **OK**

**Add Reference** (System.Configuration)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Select **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Configuration**
- Click **OK**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Add connection string(s) to the App.Config file**

- In Solution Explorer, double-click **App.Config** to open it

**App.config**:

**Note**: The `Server` and `Database` need to be changed for your environment. For more information about connection strings, see [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionStringWindowsAuthentication" connectionString="Server='.\SQLExpress'; Database='Testing'; Trusted_Connection=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ConnectionStringSqlServerAuthentication" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress; Database=Testing; User Id=|Username|; Password=|UserPassword|;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**Create a class** (name: Helper.vb)

**Note**: The code below can be adapted for use in your application (it will need to be modified for your environment). Start by checking the 'ToDo' items in the code below. Function `GetExcelColumnName` is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495651/10024425).

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Helper
    Private _connectionStr As String = String.Empty

    Sub New()
        'Windows authentication - get connection string from App.config
        _connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringWindowsAuthentication").ConnectionString
    End Sub

    Sub New(username As String, userPassword As String)
        'SQL Server authentication - get connection string from App.config
        _connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringSqlServerAuthentication").ConnectionString.Replace("|Username|", username).Replace("|UserPassword|", userPassword)
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateExcelWorkbook(filename As String, dt As DataTable) As String
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        Dim excelApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
        Dim styleDate As Excel.Style = Nothing
        Dim previousWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        Try
            'create New instance
            excelApp = New Excel.Application()

            'suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

            'set Excel visability
            excelApp.Visible = True

            'disable user control while modifying the Excel Workbook
            'to prevent user interference
            'only necessary if Excel application Visibility property = true
            'excelApp.UserControl = false

            'add workbook
            'adding a Workbook also adds a default Worksheet named "Sheet1"
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add()

            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
                'set value
                previousWorksheet = CType(excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
            End If

            'add a worksheet after the existing worksheet; excelWorksheet will be the new Worksheet
            excelWorksheet = CType(excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=previousWorksheet), Excel.Worksheet)

            'ToDo: set to desired name
            excelWorksheet.Name = "My Sheet Name"

            'indices are 1-based in Excel: (row, column)
            'A1 = Cells(1,1); B1 = Cells(1, 2)
            '
            'excelWorksheet.Cells(1, "A") = "Project Code"
            'excelWorksheet.Cells(1, "B") = "Item Code"
            '
            'excelWorksheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Project Code"
            'excelWorksheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Item Code"
            '
            'excelWorksheet.Range("A1").Value = "Project Code"
            'excelWorksheet.Range("A2").Value = "Item Code"

            'add column headers using the database column names
            For j As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                'add 1 to get excel column number; Excel indices start at 1
                Dim excelColNum As Integer = j + 1

                'set value - column header
                excelWorksheet.Cells(1, excelColNum) = dt.Columns(j).ColumnName

                'Debug.WriteLine($"Column Name: '{dt.Columns(j).ColumnName}' Data Type: '{dt.Columns(j).DataType.ToString()}'")

                'get range for column
                Dim rng As Excel.Range = CType(excelWorksheet.Cells(1, excelColNum), Excel.Range).EntireColumn

                'set data type for column
                'ToDo: change as desired
                If dt.Columns(j).DataType.ToString() = "System.DateTime" Then
                    rng.NumberFormat = "yyyy\-mm\-dd;@"
                ElseIf dt.Columns(j).DataType.ToString() = "System.Int32" Then
                    rng.NumberFormat = 0
                ElseIf dt.Columns(j).DataType.ToString() = "System.Decimal" Then
                    rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"
                End If
            Next

            'set values in Excel using data from database
            'ToDo: add desired code
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim excelRowNum As Integer = i + 2 'headers are in row 1 so data starts in row 2

                For j As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim excelColNum As Integer = j + 1

                    If dt(i)(dt.Columns(j).ColumnName) IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt(i)(dt.Columns(j).ColumnName) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                        'set cell value
                        excelWorksheet.Cells(excelRowNum, excelColNum) = dt(i)(dt.Columns(j).ColumnName).ToString()
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            'Sheet1 can be deleted
            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
                excelWorksheet = CType(excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)

                'delete existing worksheet
                excelWorksheet.Delete()
            End If

            If excelApp IsNot Nothing AndAlso excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
                'save Workbook - if file exists, overwrite it
                excelWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
            End If

            Return ($"Operation successfully completed. Created '{filename}'.")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateExcelWorkbook): " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
                excelWorkbook.Close()

                'release resources
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook)

                excelWorksheet = Nothing
                excelWorkbook = Nothing
            End If

            If excelApp IsNot Nothing Then
                excelApp.Quit()

                'release all resources
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp)
            End If
        End Try

        Return "Operation not successful"
    End Function

    Public Function Create(filename As String) As String
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataSqlServer()
        Return CreateExcelWorkbook(filename, dt)
    End Function

    Private Function GetDataSqlServer() As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            con.Open()
            Using da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Project", con)
                'get data from database
                da.Fill(dt)

                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function GetExcelColumnName(excelColumnNumber As Integer) As String
        'get column letter from column number
        'ex: given column number '1', returns 'A'

        Dim d As Integer = excelColumnNumber
        Dim m As Integer = 0
        Dim name As String = String.Empty

        Do While d > 0
            m = (d - 1) Mod 26
            name = Chr(65 + m) + name
            d = CInt((d - m) / 26)
        Loop

        Return name
    End Function
End Class
```

---

**Usage**:

**Note**: The following code assumes that there is a Button (name: btnRun) on the form and the Click event handler has been added.

```
Private _helper As Helper = Nothing
            ...

Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
    Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.Filter = "Execl files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = True
        sfd.FileName = "Test.xlsx"

        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim result As String = _helper.Create(sfd.FileName)
            Debug.WriteLine($"{result}")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

---

**Resources**

- [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com)
- [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)
- [ConfigurationManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Set data type like number, text and date in excel column using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827709/set-data-type-like-number-text-and-date-in-excel-column-using-microsoft-office)
- [How to convert a column number (e.g. 127) into an Excel column (e.g. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-e-g-127-into-an-excel-column-e-g-aa)
- [Range.NumberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)
- [Number Format Codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)
- [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlDataAdapter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlCommand Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SQL Server Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)