# Difference between CreateObject and New when opening a new excel application

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-automation, excel-automation, com-automation

What is the difference between the following two statements? I was writing a basic VB.net code which creates a new excel workbook and adds a new sheet. Both seem to be doing the same thing:

```
Dim oxl As Excel.Application
oxl = New Excel.Application
```

```
Dim oxl As Excel.Application
oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

The only thing that I note is that the VB.net editor displays the following message when I am using NEW: "Object initialization can be simplified"

Can anyone pls help?

Comment: Enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) and you'll discover the difference.

Comment: Since you are using the VBA tag: Note that VBA an vb.net are not the same. Your code is not valid as VBA code, because VBA requires use of the [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) statement for assigning an object to a variable.

Comment: The following post may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794540/10024425 (see function "CreateExcelWorkbook").

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code posted the early (or static) binding refers to compile time binding (you must add a COM reference for that):

```
Dim oxl As Excel.Application
oxl = New Excel.Application
```

And late (or dynamic) binding refers to runtime binding (for example when you use reflection) and doesn't require any COM references.

```
Dim oxl As Excel.Application
oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

You can read more about early and late binding technologies in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) article.

Comment: I do not understand why "binding" should be important here. I have shared my thoughts in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166770/confusion-in-creating-excel-application-object-using-vb-net-createobject-vs-new/74170413?noredirect=1#comment130973754_74170413. Could you please check my most recent comments there (u shall find it against the comments given by @Craig in the answer given by Andrew Morton)

Comment: Here the question was about the difference between the `CreateObject` and `New`. So, I've answered it.